# Openlayers 3.18.2 vector tiles - horizontal and vertical line artifacts

Tags: openlayers, vector-tiles

When rendering a vector tile layer in Openlayers 3.18.2 i get horizontal and vertical line artifacts on some zoom levels. When zooming in or out they vanish or appear on other places. I tried to use different render modes, with no effects. It is also browser independent (tested on Chrome and Firefox)

Layer Code:

```
var vector_tile_layer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
        source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
          attributions: attribution,
          format: new ol.format.MVT(),
          tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 20}),
          tilePixelRatio: 16,
          overlaps: false,
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/data/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf'
        }),
        style: function(feature) {
          var kgnr = feature.get('KG_NR');
          if (kgnr % 3 == 0) {
            color = '#000000';
          }else if(kgnr % 3 == 1){
            color = '#91AA00';
          }else if (kgnr % 3 == 2){
            color = '#F1A4C3';
          }


            style = new ol.style.Style({
              stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: color,
                width: 1
              })

            });


          return style;
        },
        options: {
            'renderMode': 'vector'
        },
      });
```

Sample image (all straight vertical and straight horizontal lines are artifacts):

[image: line artifacts]

Any ideas anyone?